# C4716 function must return a value thown despite returning a value

Tags: c++, qt

The problem is that the compiler (Mingw32) insists that there is a compilier error at line 21 in "util.h".

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "treeitem.h"
using namespace std;

#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <cctype>
#include <locale>
#include <QList>


static inline string &ltrim(string &s){}
static inline string &rtrim(string &s){}
static inline string &trim(string &s){}
static inline string func_1(string txt,size_t start, size_t end){}
static inline size_t func_2(string txt, size_t index){}
static inline string replace(string& str, const string& from, const string& to){}
vector<TreeItem *> parse(string dat){}

#endif // UTIL_H
```

Line 21 is just a placeholder for the function in "util.cpp". 
(Snippet of util.cpp)

```
vector<TreeItem *> parse(string dat)
{
    vector<TreeItem *> final {};
    while (dat.find("{") <= dat.length()){
        TreeItem * temp = new TreeItem;
        temp->setText(QString::fromStdString(replace(replace(replace(replace(trim(func_1(dat,0,dat.find('{'))),"\n","")," ",""),"}",""),"=","")));
        QList<TreeItem *> ref = parse(func_1(dat, dat.find("{")+1,func_2(dat,dat.find('{'))));

        for(int j = 0; j < ref.size(); j++)
        {
            temp->setParent(ref.at(j));
            final.push_back(temp);
            dat = func_1(dat,func_2(dat,dat.find('{')),dat.length());
        }
    }
    return final;
}
```

Obviously it returns something so the compiler shouldn't be giving an error. It isn't a problem with the loop always evaluating to true because even if I move "return final;" in front of the loop it still throws the error.

Comment: What are those `{}` doing in the header file???

Comment: **WHAT'S THE COMPILER ERROR?**  Without that, we're really not able to help you.

Comment: @MaxLybbert: It's in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems are in the lines:

```
static inline string &ltrim(string &s){}
static inline string &rtrim(string &s){}
static inline string &trim(string &s){}
static inline string func_1(string txt,size_t start, size_t end){}
static inline size_t func_2(string txt, size_t index){}
static inline string replace(string& str, const string& from, const string& to){}
vector<TreeItem *> parse(string dat){}
```

All of them provide an empty implementation, they are not just declarations. If you want them to be just declarations, you need to replace the `{}` by a `;`.

```
static inline string &ltrim(string &s);
static inline string &rtrim(string &s);
static inline string &trim(string &s);
static inline string func_1(string txt,size_t start, size_t end);
static inline size_t func_2(string txt, size_t index);
static inline string replace(string& str, const string& from, const string& to);
vector<TreeItem *> parse(string dat);
```

Comment: Shouldn't an `inline` function have the body, so that the compiler can expand it when it sees the use?

Comment: @Barmar, a function can be declared inline and defined later on.

Answer (score 3):

remove the braces in the header. You define prototypes in the header and the implementation in the source file.